# Combining columns from two unrelated tables in SQL

Tags: sql, hana-sql-script

Let's say I have two tables

Table 1

```
COl_1 COl_2

1     5
2     6
3     7
4     8
```

AND Table 2

```
COL3    COL4
9      13
10     14
11     15
12     16
```

I want the following:

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL3    COL4
1        5        9     13
2        6        10    14
3        7        11    15
4        8        12    16
```

Also, the number of rows are exactly the same everytime in each of the tables,
no key relation or integrity stuff.

Any clue?

Comment: then add a relation column.

Comment: How? The tables are already populated. How do I add a unique column to them?

Comment: Check the below answer, you can always return extra columns besides table's columns ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `row_number()` to add a "join" key to the two tables:

```
select t1.col_1, t1.col_2, t2.col_3, t2.col_4
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by col_1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by col_3) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

If the tables have different numbers of rows, you might want an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an identity column as an alternative to row_number() as follows

```
alter table Table_1 add id int identity(1,1)
alter table Table_2 add id int identity(1,1)
```

Then using this ID column, you can join both tables as follows (as LONG suggested FULL JOIN)

```
select col1, col2, COL3, COL4
from Table_1
full outer join Table_2 on Table_1.id = Table_2.id
```

With some additional data you can get following results

[image]